# Types definitions are not available in .test.ts file

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings

I can pretty well use my types in .ts but for some reason, I don't understand why It's failing on .test.ts though both files exist under the same folder.

In .ts file

[image]

In .test.ts file

[image]

[image]

Comment: Need to see actual code. `test.ts` isn't a thing BTW. It's just like any `.ts` file

Comment: I get that too but It has been acting up I don't understand why. I think the issue is not the code but probably the configuration -- which I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: More information is still required. There are dozens of reasons that could be happening

Comment: Never mind @AluanHaddad, I've figured out why. 
Like I said, it's not the code but the configurations. 

```  "exclude": ["node_modules", "src/**/*.test.ts"]``` Just made few minutes ago and it raised that error.

Comment: And thanks for your quick reply

Comment: That would do it, but there's no way to know that that's the problem you're having because you didn't provide your configuration. Therefore this isn't a good question

Comment: Anyone trying to answer would just be shooting in the dark but I'm glad you got it working

Comment: @AluanHaddad yeah you're absolutely right, shooting in dark . I am sorry about that as well. Next time I will mind giving more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone else is facing this same issue, 
Just exclude `"src/**/*.test.ts"` in `"exclude": ["node_modules", "src/**/*.test.ts"]` in your `tsconfig.json`